# glutCloseFunc without terminating application

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freeglut, glutcreatewindow

I have created a window with `glutCreateWindow` and started a loop using `glutMainLoop`. I want to end that loop and close the window so I use `glutLeaveMainLoop` and `glutCloseFunc` to destroy it. Automatically, my application terminates.

I would like the application to persist after the window is destroyed. Is it possible?

According to this [link](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glutclosefunc) I can do it, however I don't know how. I'm using *freeglut*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [the doc for `glutCloseFunc()`](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#WindowCallback):

> Users looking to prevent FreeGLUT from exiting when a window is closed, should look into using `glutSetOption` to set `GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE`.

which leads to [the `glutSetOption()` docs](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#StateSetting):

> `GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE` - Controls what happens when a window is closed by the user or system:
>
> - `GLUT_ACTION_EXIT` will immediately exit the application (default, GLUT's behavior).
> - `GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS` will immediately return from the main loop.
> - `GLUT_ACTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION` will continue execution of remaining windows.

And from [`glutLeaveMainLoop()`](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php#EventProcessing):

> The `glutLeaveMainLoop` function causes freeglut to stop the event loop. If the `GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE` option has been set to `GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS` or `GLUT_ACTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION`, control will return to the function which called glutMainLoop; otherwise the application will exit.

Putting the pieces together:

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutSetOption( GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE, GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS ); 
    std::cout << "Before glutMainLoop()!" << std::endl;
    glutMainLoop();
    std::cout << "Back in main()!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's an accurate answer, thanks. Flag `GLUT_ACTION_EXIT` was set by default, that's why my application exited.

Comment: is `glutSetOption` part of the current 3.7 version?

Comment: @galois: No, `glutSetOption()` is not in the [GLUT 3.7 spec](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/spec3.html), it's a [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/)/OpenGLUT extension, hence the `#include <GL/freeglut.h>` instead of `#include <GL/glut.h>`.

Comment: @genpfault thanks, I figured as such. pretty new to OpenGL and still having a hell of a time differentiating everything.