# Application closed entirely when closing a pyopengl window

Tags: glut, opengl-3, pyside2, pyopengl

I have a GUI  developed with pyside2, i have a button in this GUI, when clicking on it, a pyopengl window appears and showing what is needed. The problem is that when closing this window, the entire GUI closed. I want to continue using the GUI after closing the opengl window.
I'm using GLUT to create the window.

my_GUI_mainwindow.py:
    import pyopengl
    ...
    ...
    ...
    self.Btn.clicked.connect(self.opengl)
    def opengl(self):
        pyopengl(file_m)

my_pyopengl.py:

```
    glutInit()
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH)
    glutInitWindowSize(pyopengl.g_Width, pyopengl.g_Height)
    glutCreateWindow(self.fileName)
    self.init()
    glutReshapeFunc(self.reshape)
    glutDisplayFunc(self.display)
    glutMouseFunc(self.mouse)
    glutMotionFunc(self.motion)
    glutKeyboardFunc(self.keyboard)
    glutMainLoop()
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Sorry i forget to put my code. Done.

Comment: You might want to take a look at setting a flag to prevent your app from terminating, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36992051/2588654).

Comment: @Joelle Why don't you use QOpenGlWidget? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57718621/6622587

Comment: @Joelle The problem is that each way to create a window (Qt and GLUT) has an eventloop that when you open the new window will block the previous one.